How struct is not padding in given program
I am trying to understand below C program
#include <stdio.h>

//#pragma pack(1)

struct var1 {
    char data1;
    char arr1[10];
};

union var2 {
    int data2;
    char arr2[5];
};

int main(void){
    printf("var1: %lu, var2: %lu\n", sizeof(struct var1), sizeof(union var2));
    return 0;
}

The output of it
 gcc-12 -Wall struct-union.c

output
var1: 11, var2: 8

Why var1 is not 12 bytes?
environment
 Linux n 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


Aside: Use %zu to print a size_t, not %lu.  There is no guarantee they're the same.

Why should it be 12 rather than 11?  There's nothing there that requires a tighter alignment than a single byte, so the size can be 11 without causing problems.

@JonathanLeffler hmm, var1 have all single byte elements that's why it don't need alignment?

Padding is likely. Do you known what that is?

struct var1 is 1 + 10 = 11 bytes, padded to a 1-byte multiple, so 11 bytesl.  union var2 is max(4,5) = 5 bytes, padded to a 4-byte multiple, so 8 bytes.  Note that sizes and padding are machine-specific, so you may see different results on other machines.

Can I say this, compiler adds padding only for processor to comfortably access members. In this case no padding is required as each element is byte addressable. IIf a member is not single byte addressable, padding needs to be done.

@mrigendra On your machine, padding is needed for union var2, since it contains an int, which on your machine requires 4-byte alignment.  This means the entire union needs to be padded to a multiple of 4 bytes.  If it weren't, consider what would happen if you had an array of union var2 elements.

@mrigendra — that's the way compilers normally work, yes.
